# Oracle Sequence Field Increments Based On Different Field

Tags: oracle, plsql

I know SQL Server.  On a project using Oracle and having a heck of a time doing things.  My current issue is that we have a table that is similar to the following:

```
ACCOUNT_ID   NUMBER
SEQUENCE_ID  NUMBER
DISPLAY_NAME VARCHAR2
TOKEN        VARCHAR2
PAYMENT_TYPE NUMBER
```

The Account_ID can occur multiple times in this table.  What I need is the Sequence_ID needs to Increment uniquely for each Account_ID.  So looking something like this.

```
ACCOUNT_ID    SEQUENCE_ID    DISPLAY_NAME    TOKEN    PAYMENT_TYPE
------------------------------------------------------------------
111111        1              Primary         abcd     1
222222        1              Primary         bcde     1
222222        2              Secondary       dffs     1
333333        1              Default         fdsf     2
111111        2              Alternate       sfff     2
222222        3              Another         slsl     1
```

As you can see, the Account_ID of 11111 has 2 records and the Sequence_ID does not repeat for that Account_ID.  Basically, Sequence_ID is auto-incrementing but uniquely for each Account_ID.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible but not with sequence. Stored procedure or Function has to be incorporated for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encapsulate all the logic in a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_Account(
  in_account_id    IN ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_ID%TYPE,
  in_display_name  IN ACCOUNTS.DISPLAY_NAME%TYPE,
  in_token         IN ACCOUNTS.TOKEN%TYPE,
  in_payment_type  IN ACCOUNTS.PAYMENT_TYPE%TYPE
)
AS
  p_seq_id ACCOUNTS.SEQUENCE_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
  INTO   p_seq_no
  FROM   ACCOUNTS
  WHERE  ACCOUNT_ID = in_account_id;

  INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS (
    account_id,
    sequence_id,
    display_name,
    token,
    payment_type
  ) VALUES (
    in_account_id,
    p_seq_id,
    in_display_name,
    in_token,
    in_payment_type
  );
END;
/
```

Or you could just use an `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS
SELECT :account_id,
       COUNT(*) + 1,
       :display_name,
       :token,
       :payment_type
FROM   ACCOUNTS
WHERE  account_id = :account_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest solution to your problem would be to create a trigger on your table, like this:

```
create or replace trigger yourtable_biu
    before insert or update of ACCOUNT_ID on yourtable
    referencing new as new old as old
    for each row
begin
    select count(*) into :new.SEQUENCE_ID from yourtable where ACCOUNT_ID = new.ACCOUNT_ID;
end;
/
```

Comment: Wouldn't encourage using Triggers for [these](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/5806.trigger-disadvantages) reasons. Unless and until there's no other way out.

Comment: @SameerMirji i really don't think triggers are so evil and that this link is still relevant, but of course all should be taken into consideration...

Answer (score 0):

> As illustrated in the above answer perfectly you can use Procedure to
>   do this. If you don't want to use everything in Procedure, you can use
>   function as you can use the return value of function in any way. Hope this
>   helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_Account(
  in_account_id    IN ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_ID%TYPE,
  in_display_name  IN ACCOUNTS.DISPLAY_NAME%TYPE,
  in_token         IN ACCOUNTS.TOKEN%TYPE,
  in_payment_type  IN ACCOUNTS.PAYMENT_TYPE%TYPE
)
RETURN PLS_INTEGER
AS
  p_seq_id ACCOUNTS.SEQUENCE_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
  INTO   p_seq_no
  FROM   ACCOUNTS
  WHERE  ACCOUNT_ID = in_account_id;

RETURN p_seq_no;
END;
```

Comment: So, we can return values from a procedure as well. I don't see why function is better than procedure here.

Comment: You appear to have copied my procedure header and part of the body verbatim but you are only using one of the input values so the rest are redundant. It would also be useful if you show how this can be used in an `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Yes as I mentioned in my answer that your answer is perfect in this case. But the whole point was to separate out the DML transaction from the seq generation. Same thing an procedure can be called for DML which can use this function to get the seq.

Comment: @Sameer: To make modularity in the code I suggested to use function. Same function can be used else where where this kind of situation arises.